# Add Airplay Icon to AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

The following code enables AirPlay and adds an AirPlay icon to the AVPlayer view:

```
        playerViewController.player?.allowsExternalPlayback = true

        var volumeView = MPVolumeView()
        volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false
        volumeView.sizeToFit()

        playerViewController.view.addSubview(volumeView)

        playerViewController.player!.play()
```

However, it does it in the wrong location - the AirPlay icon appears in the top left. How can I ensure it appears next to the volume controls?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question I have the exact same thing. It appears in the top left corner instead of next to the controls.